# Docusign Connect Message to return UserId in addition to RecipientId

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create a listener for Docusign Connect. The connect message returns the UserName and RecipientId. The problem is that my recipient is actually a signing group so the recipient ID is not unique to the users and I need to cross-reference that the email is a valid user on my end. Is there any way that the User ID is returned?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you get the SigningGroupID from the connect response you could use the REST API endpoint below to get the list of users that are part of that signing group. This should allow you to verify if the right emails are being used. Let me know if that helps.

API Endpoint:

```
    GET {vx}/accounts/{accountid}/signing_groups/{signinggroupid}
```

[SigningGroups: get docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/SigningGroups/SigningGroups/get/)

Expected Response:

```
    { 
        "signingGroupId": "sample string 1",
        "groupName": "sample string 2",
        "groupType": "sample string 3",
        "groupEmail": "sample string 4",
        "created": "sample string 5",
        "createdBy": "sample string 6",
        "modified": "sample string 7",
        "modifiedBy": "sample string 8",
        "users": [{
            "userName": "sample string 1",
            "email": "sample string 2",
            "errorDetails": {
                "errorCode": "sample string 1",
                "message": "sample string 2"
            }
        }],
        "errorDetails": {
            "errorCode": "SUCCESS",
            "message": ""
        }
    }
```

Comment: I ended up getting the envelope recipient signers for two main reasons: the signing group may already have been deleted and the email address in the connect message may have been malformed (unescaped illegal characters in the XML). So basically, I'm just using the connect hook to listen for any activity and based on the status of the recipients (regardless of who they are), I just fire an API call to get the recipient list since it includes the same information anyway (rendering the rest of the soap envelope useless :)). Thanks for the help!